# Would you rather say "build a program under a specific operating system" or "on an operating system"?

Tags: prepositions

I have seen both usages on different sites, but somehow the latter feels more idiomatic to me (not a native speaker):

- ["Instructions for building under Windows"](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/6.4.2/docs/html/building/winbuild.html)
- ["Building under Windows"](https://wiki.dlang.org/Building_under_Windows)
- ["Building from source under Windows"](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChBuildInstallWinBuild.html)

versus

- ["Build from source on Windows"](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows)
- ["How to build CARLA on Windows"](https://carla.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.4/how_to_build_on_windows/)
- ["Instructions on how to build SUMO on Windows", actually the same site uses both prepositions](https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Installing/Windows_Build.html)

Is there one version that should be preferred over the other?

Comment: Speaking as a hobbyist, not a professional (and speaking only because nobody identifying as a pro has stepped in yet), they both sound correct. To me, "under" is more common among pro technical folks, and "on" is more commonplace among the rest of us.

Answer (score 2):

I (American English speaker) would prefer **on**, though **under** doesn't sound incorrect.